# How to stop splicer render

Tags: c#, .net, renderer, splicer

I am using Splicer from 
[here](https://splicer.codeplex.com/) with c#

```
using (WindowsMediaRenderer renderer = new WindowsMediaRenderer(timeline, "output.wmv", WindowsMediaProfiles.HighQualityVideo))
    {
        renderer.Render();
        // How to Stop this render
    }
}
```

I found way to use `progressParticipant`

```
PercentageProgressParticipant progressParticipant = new PercentageProgressParticipant(timeline);
progressParticipant.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<Splicer.Renderer.ProgressChangedEventArgs>(progressParticipant_ProgressChanged);
```

and changed renderer contractor to

```
using (WindowsMediaRenderer renderer =new WindowsMediaRenderer(timeline, "output.wmv", WindowsMediaProfiles.HighQualityVideo, new ICallbackParticipant[] { progressParticipant },null))
{
    renderer.Render();
}
```

`ProgressChanged` Method

```
public void progressParticipant_ProgressChanged(object sender, Splicer.Renderer.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       double D = double.Parse(e.Progress.ToString())*100.0;
       int P = (int)D;
       _bw.ReportProgress(P);
   }
```

Can I use `ICallbackParticipant` or any other way to stop render ?